# JPA HIbernate - ManyToOne mapping - insert if not exists

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have the below 2 classes(entities).

Person Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.SEQUENCE, 
  generator="person_id_seq")
  @SequenceGenerator(name="person_id_seq", sequenceName="person_id_seq", 
  allocationSize=1)
  private Integer person_id;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
  @JoinColumn(name = "location_id")
  private Location location;
}
```

Location Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "location")
public class Location {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "location_seq_gen")
  @SequenceGenerator(name = "location_seq_gen", sequenceName = "location_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
  @Column(name = "location_id")
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "address_1")
  private String address1;

  @Column(name = "address_2")
  private String address2;

  @Column(name = "city")
  private String city;

  @Column(name = "state")
  private String state;

  @Column(name = "zip")
  private String zipCode;

  @Column(name = "location_source_value")
  private String locationSourceValue;

public Location() {
}

public Location(String address1, String address2, String city, String state, String zipCode) {
    this.address1 = address1;
    this.address2 = address2;
    this.city = city;
    this.state = state;
    this.zipCode = zipCode;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public Long getId(String address1, String address2, String city, String state, String zipCode){
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getAddress1() {
    return address1;
}

public void setAddress1(String address1) {
    this.address1 = address1;
}

public String getAddress2() {
    return address2;
}

public void setAddress2(String address2) {
    this.address2 = address2;
}

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

public String getState() {
    return state;
}

public void setState(String state) {
    this.state = state;
}

public String getZipCode() {
    return zipCode;
}

public void setZipCode(String zipCode) {
    this.zipCode = zipCode;
}

public String getLocationSourceValue() {
    return locationSourceValue;
}

public void setLocationSourceValue(String locationSourceValue) {
    this.locationSourceValue = locationSourceValue;
}
```

}

What I want to be able to do is the following.

- When I insert a new Person record, I will provide the addressLine1, addressLine2, city, state, zipcode and it should check in the Location table if the record exists. If it exists, then get the location_id from the Location table and insert the new Person record with the existing location_id. If it does NOT exist, create a new record in the Location table, get the location_id and use that as the location_id for the new Person record.

I believe this can be achieved with the appropriate JPA Hibernate annotations.

Currently, whenever I am inserting a new Person record, it is creating a new record in the Location table even if the Location exists.

Please help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Have you overrided equals and hashCode methods? By this method you will add identifying each row in the table. You have specified annotations properly, but Hibernate can't determine if this row exists or not. Internally Hibernate uses Map, so equals and hashCode should solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Please can you elaborate this with an example.

Comment: Please look into this link
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/persistent-classes.html#persistent-classes-equalshashcode

Here you can find why do you need override these methods and samples.

Comment: @Sergiy Rezvan I am facing the same issue, but I dont clearly understand what is specified either. Please elaborate on what changes should be made in the entity tables.

Comment: @SergiyRezvan Thank you for pointing to the documentation but it is not clear enough. Also, I tried the above example with a simple code https://dzone.com/tutorials/java/hibernate/hibernate-example/hibernate-mapping-many-to-one-using-annotations-1.html. In this, if I give it to a constructor it works but it does not work when I set it using a setter method.

Comment: @SergiyRezvan any help please